# Parse Library missing bitcode?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, bitcode

I'm am building to an iphone running iOS9 on xcode 7.1.1  The project uses the parse framework and I get this linker error

`ld: '/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/motorvate-ios2-master/Pods/ParseFacebookUtils/libParseFacebookUtilsLib.a(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I'm aware of the new bitcode requirements and the app-thining paradigm but am unfamiliar with how to implement it.  Is this something on parses end or can I resolve it myself?

Comment: your application is also supported in iWatch ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using pod to integrate parse ? if yes than it should be resolved ...

delete your derived data and make clean-rebuild again

see here the discussion

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/254